# How do these hexadecimal values return true?

Tags: c#, .net, hex

While working on a Github project I came across a line like the picture & code below and I am baffled as to how it returns true. Thanks!

**The Code:**

    `Console.WriteLine((0x90 & 0x10) == 0x10);`
**The Expected Result:**

False
**The Result:**

True

[image: Code]

I just don't understand how when comparing **0x90** and **0x10** to see if they are the same, it returns true. Is it because **0x90** is divisble by **0x10**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a [bitwise and](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0zec0b2.aspx). `(0x90 & 0x10) == 0x10` because the set of all bits `0x90` and `0x10` happen to have in common, happens to be the same as the set of all bits that are "on" in 0x10. There's only one bit in this particular case.

Bitwise and means "give me a new number where each bit is 1 if and only if that bit is one in *both* of these numbers".

So when I line up the numbers one above the other (*right* aligned -- notice that I pad from the left with zeros so they're the same width), follow down each column to get the result for that column: If it's 1 in both rows up top, it's 1 in the bottom row. If it's zero in *either* row up top, it's zero on the bottom.

```
     10010000    // == 0x90
 &   00010000    // == 0x10
-------------
     00010000    // == 0x10
```

Bitwise operations are wildly counterintuitive until you write out the zeroes and ones and line them up by columns.

Here's another example: 0x98 & 0x18 == 0x18:

```
     10011000    // == 0x98
 &   00011000    // == 0x18
-------------
     00011000    // == 0x18
```

And one final example:

```
     10001100    // == 0x8C
 &   00011000    // == 0x18
-------------
     00001000    // == 0x10
```

Comment: Could you edit and explain more please? Do you mean each bit in the byte is non-zero?

Comment: But the question had 0x90, which definitely does share a bit with 0x10, hence the "true" result...

Comment: @SeanMitchell See further update that's actually correct. Sorry!

Comment: @EdPlunkett So, it returns true because the one bit is the same?Just one of them has to be true?

Comment: @SeanMitchell See new update. In my second example, they have two bits in common, but we're comparing to a number that has both those bits, so the comparison is true.

Comment: The bitwise-and processes the number bit-position by bit-position. Only if the 2 input bits are 1, the correponding bit-position in the result becomes 1 and otherwise 0. I.e., `0 & 0 == 0`, `0 & 1 == 0`, `1 & 0 == 0`, `1 & 1 == 1`.

Comment: I get it now! TYSM!

Answer (score 0):

If you look at them as bits:

```
0x90: 10010000
0x10: 00010000
```

Bitwise-and picks the columns where both numbers have a 1 you get

00010000

Which is 0x10

In constrast 0x90 | 0x10 would be 0x90 because it is the columns where at least one number has a 1:

If you want to try it out for yourself, the Windows Calculator app in programmer mode lets you perform bitwise operations and easily convery from hex to bin

Answer (score 0):

000**1 0000**==0x10

100**1 0000**==0x90

&

000**1 0000**==0x10

===============

(0x90 & 0x10) equals 0x10

so

0x10 == 0x10

it is true

Comment: So when it reaches the first bit that is the same in both it takes that and all the following zeros and then compares the result?

Comment: @SeanMitchell The **&** takes all the bits that are nonzero in both numbers -- in this case, there happens to be only one, but there could be two or more. That's a completely separate operation from the **==**.